# The method read(File) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, javax.imageio

So when I replace the urlImage to an actual image path e.g. "BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read("F:/Java/data/photo.jpg") on the first line of the code it return the following error "The method read(File) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the arguments (String)" I tried different things but it didn't work, it may sound obvious, I just wasn't able to convert the String type to File.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(urlImage);
int x;
int y;
int c = image.getRGB(x,y);
int  red = (c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int  green = (c & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int  blue = c & 0x000000ff;
// and the Java Color is ...
Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
```

Comment: replaced it from what with what?

Comment: an actual image url

Comment: that's not a data type. The error is very clear that it needs a `File` as argument, so what _was_ it, and what did you replace it with? Because the error suggests it was a `File`, you replaced it with a `String`, and the error is telling you what you did wrong.

Comment: fair enough, it was a newbie question

Comment: You still haven't answered the question though: what was there before, and what did you replace it with? (and remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I changed some things, does it sound reasonable now? I know it was a obvious and dumb question but it was a genuine one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method read(File) in the type ImageIO is not applicable for the
> arguments (String)

is a pretty clear error. You are passing an String where you need to pass a File. Just do:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(urlImage));
```

Comment: thanks, I knew that just wasn't able to fix it